# Year sum dataframe per label

Tags: r

Having a data structure as this one:

```
dtest <- data.frame(label=c("yahoo","google","yahoo","yahoo","google","google","yahoo","yahoo"), year=c(2000,2001,2000,2001,2003,2003,2003,2003))
```

How is it possible to extract a new dataframe like this one:

`doutput <- data.frame(label=c("yahoo","yahoo","yahoo","yahoo","google","google","google","google"), year=c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2000,2001,2002,2003), volume=c(2,1,0,3,0,1,0,2))`

> ```
> > doutput
>    label year volume
> 1  yahoo 2000      2
> 2  yahoo 2001      1
> 3  yahoo 2002      0
> 4  yahoo 2003      3
> 5 google 2000      0
> 6 google 2001      1
> 7 google 2002      0
> 8 google 2003      2
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dtest %>%
  group_by(label, year) %>%
  tally(name = "volume")

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   label [2]
  label   year volume
  <fct>  <dbl>  <int>
1 google  2001      1
2 google  2003      2
3 yahoo   2000      2
4 yahoo   2001      1
5 yahoo   2003      2
```

Comment: Hi. I try to reproduce your example but I receive this error: Error in tally(., name = "volume") : unused argument (name = "volume") I use the dtest as the question data

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with base R:

```
as.data.frame(table(transform(dtest,
                              year = factor(year, levels = seq(min(year), max(year))))))
```

The result:

```
   label year Freq
1 google 2000    0
2  yahoo 2000    2
3 google 2001    1
4  yahoo 2001    1
5 google 2002    0
6  yahoo 2002    0
7 google 2003    2
8  yahoo 2003    2
```